# Linux - Transmit Packet Steering (XPS) issue

Tags: linux, networking, linux-device-driver

I have a network driver (driver interface eth1) with 12 TX queues and running under 12 CPU cores.

I am using Amazon Linux 2: 4.14.243-185.433.amzn2.x86_64

I am trying to use XPS to steer TX packets for each queue to a single core (according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.10/networking/scaling.html)

To config the XPS, I run the following:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-0/xps_cpus
echo 2 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-1/xps_cpus
echo 4 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-2/xps_cpus
echo 8 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-3/xps_cpus
echo 10 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-4/xps_cpus
echo 20 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-5/xps_cpus
echo 40 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-6/xps_cpus
echo 80 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-7/xps_cpus
echo 100 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-8/xps_cpus
echo 200 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-9/xps_cpus
echo 400 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-10/xps_cpus
echo 800 > /sys/class/net/eth1/queues/tx-11/xps_cpus
```

Using iperf2, when sending single flow (single queue) it doesn't seem to use the xps configuration above, every run, a different CPU will start and transmit the flow even if source/dest IP and ports stay the same.
it also doesn't seem to choose the same queue every time, any reason why?
command:

`iperf -c 1.2.3.4 -p 5001 -B 5.6.7.8:5002`

Tried also to bind the iperf to specific core and it still didn't work:

`numactl --physcpubind=0 iperf -c 1.2.3.4 -p 5001 -B 5.6.7.8:5002`

Validated that the driver is calling `__netdev_pick_tx` to choose the queue index:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4....re/dev.c#L3196

Any other thing needs to be done to enable XPS?

how to check if CONFIG_XPS is enabled?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question on why it chooses a different queue every time, it may be due to a connection hash which is different every time.
Generally for fixed known connections (src ip, dst ip, src port, dst port) it will always be a unique queue, but iperf gets launched every time with random TCP/UDP ports.
That's why the connection hash changes, probably to pick up different queue. With netperf, you can always run with fixed ports using the `-- -P` option.

```
netperf -H 20.0.0.18 -t TCP_STREAM -- -P 6660,5550
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe numactl or taskset affinities are not governed by iperf and friends for some reason, I also faced this problem many times although you can try below iperf3 with -A option. It may affinitize iperf client on this core.

iperf3 -c 192.168.40.100 -A5,5 -t 23456 -P 1

It's possible that the core who is running the connection is not from the cores you have set for XPS. XPS is basically for a given core to decide which queue to be selected if it's mask is found in one of the queue's xps_cpus and if that core (which is unknown at the moment who is running that connection) is not in xps_cpus queue config then it could select any random queue based on packet/connection hash.

if you need to find out which core is running the connection, then let's say at run time the queue 0 is used (based on ethtool -S ethx counter) for transmit, try one by one setting all the cores in system to queue 1 (it could be any queue other than the queue 0) xps_cpus and see for which core set the traffic got switched on the queue 1 (based on ethtool -S ethx again), that will be the core who is running your connection actually.

HTH
Thanks,
Manish

Comment: One can bind an iperf/netperf/whatnot process to a given CPU, but that will not alter the RSS hash being performed by the (virtual) NIC, so the return traffic with TCP (ACKs) will be processed on the CPU which took the interrupt.  And the CPU which takes the interrupt will be determined by the queue on which the NIC puts the packet, and where the interrupts are assigned for that queue.
And for an outbound transfer, if the sending application (eg iperf/netperf/whatnot) has built-up a queue of traffic to send, arriving ACKs will cause outbound traffic, which will happen on that same CPU.